# Using a short cage derailleur: Buying maximum cassette teeth

Tags: cassette

Hi I know the maximum limit for short cage derailleur is 11-30. So I recently had just changed my chains on a bike shop and I was using a 11-28 cassette before and after I just change the chain. So the question is can I still use the 11-30? Will it like somehow affect the chain being too short since it's just only 2 teeth difference?

Answer (score 1):

No problem to use a cassette that is 2-teeth bigger or smaller (the way the question is formulated is not clear, but the answer would be the same). You may need to adjust the b-screw, that allow to change the distance between the cassette and the cage, and make sure that the chain has the correct length.

Just a note: the maximum limits for "a short cage derailleur" depends on the specs of the derailleur, you have some variation among derailleurs.

Comment: If I bought the new one which is the same as my old cassette(11-28), do I still need adjust the limit screw?

Comment: @Acuityo very unlikely, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the chain and it’s length: a chain sized for an 11-28 should still work with an 11-30. I would avoid shifting into the big-big combo, which you should avoid anyway due to increased drivetrain friction and chain wear. However, it should work. One way to verify this is put your bike in a stand and shift into big-big while turning the cranks gingerly. If the chain is much too short, the wheel should stop immediately; if this were done at full power you’d damage things like the RD itself.

Presumably you and/or the store did quickly verify that the chain wasn’t worn. A worn out chain on a new cassette will quickly kill the cassette, as you may already know.